# setting Document Root

Tags: php, open-basedir

When I set document root it prevents me from going back any further in directories. Is that anywhere near equivalent in protecting from a directory traversal attack as setting the open_base directive?

Comment: I don't think this will be enough to prevent you from directory traversal.